# C# Atribuir um Form a uma variavel

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou com uma dificuldade de conseguir resolver esse problema.

Criei um projeto em Windows Form para abrir os outros formuláros dentro de um panel, sendo que gostaria de associar os Formulários a serem abertos nas variávies no inicio dos código, poís tenho que fazer referência a esse Formulários varias vezes durante o código, gostaria de declara-los apenas uma vez em uma variável para utilizar a variavel ao invés dos Forms nos Click dos buttons mais não consegui.

```
    Form Formulario1;// Gostaria de colocar o Form a ser aberto aqui e utilizar aenas a variavel
    Form Formulario2;// Gostaria de colocar o Form a ser aberto aqui e utilizar aenas a variavel
    Form Formulario3;// Gostaria de colocar o Form a ser aberto aqui e utilizar aenas a variavel
    Form Formulario4;// Gostaria de colocar o Form a ser aberto aqui e utilizar aenas a variavel

    private void Abrir_Formulario<MiForm>() where MiForm : Form, new()
    {
        Form formulario;
        formulario = panel_Formularios.Controls.OfType<MiForm>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (formulario == null)
        {
            formulario = new MiForm();
            formulario.SuspendLayout();
            formulario.TopLevel = false;
            formulario.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            formulario.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            panel_Formularios.Controls.Add(formulario);
            panel_Formularios.Tag = formulario;
            formulario.Show();
            formulario.BringToFront();
            formulario.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(Fechar_Formulario);
            formulario.ResumeLayout();
        }
        else
        {
            formulario.BringToFront();
        }
    }

     // BOTÃO FORMULARIO 1
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Abrir_Formulario<Form1>();// Ideal esse Form vir da variavel no inicio 
    }

    // BOTÃO FORMULARIO 2
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Abrir_Formulario<Form2>(); // Ideal esse Form vir da variavel no inicio 
    }

    // BOTÃO FORMULARIO 3
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Abrir_Formulario<Form3>();// Ideal esse Form vir da variavel no inicio 
    }

    // BOTÃO FORMULARIO 4
    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Abrir_Formulario<Form4>();// Ideal esse Form vir da variavel no inicio 
    }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: na variavel `Application.OpenForms` você tem a coleção de forms que está aberto na aplicação, basta acessá-los... não precisa ficar guardando cada um... se ainda assim quiser fazer uma lista paralela, use um `List<Form>`  https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.openforms?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: O que você deve considerar: O form será reutilizado? Se sim, não deve chamar Close(), use Hide(). Caso chame Hide() o form reterá o estado (campos, propriedades, etc), você pode criar um método ResetFields() (ou similar) para limpar o form. Talvez seja mais conveniente criar um novo Form ao invés de resetar o seu estado, veja o que lhe cai melhor.

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia, se eu entendi bem voce quer abrir um formulario dentro de um painel
tenta da seguinte maneira
primeiro declare essa variavel do formulario
exemplo frmBuscarClientes.

```
    private frmBuscarClientes BuscarClientes = null;
//aqui voce verifica se ja esta aberto, para nao fica abrindo varios formularios
    if (Application.OpenForms.OfType<frmBuscarClientes>().Count() > 0)
                    {
                        this.BuscarClientes.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
                        //Aqui e caso esteja minimzado o formulario abra o mesmo ao invés de um novo
    
                    }
                    else
                    {
    
                        this.BuscarClientes = new frmBuscarClientes();
                        this.BuscarClientes.Text = "Buscar Clientes";//titulo do formulario
                        this.BuscarClientes.TopLevel = false;
                        
                        this.BuscarClientes.Visible = true;
                        this.BuscarClientes.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Sizable;//borda
                        gbPrincipal.Controls.Add(BuscarClientes);//BuscarCliente é a variavel do fomulário
                        //gbPrincipal é o nome do painel
                    }
```

// tenta a partir dai garanto que vai chegar em algo bom.
// so repetir o codigo para outros formualrios.

pode colocar em uma função.